# PL/SQL List of items, check if record exists, if yes update if not create

Tags: plsql, sql-update

Im trying to learn PL/SQL and I was given an assignment which I am not sure how to tackle.

I am given a list of orders. I want to check my ORDER table for each of them in the following way:

1. Check if order exists, if no create a record
2. Check if order fullfilled (0 or 1)
3. If order is not fullfilled (0), update to 1

I put together a script which I think can do this for one order, but I'm sure it's not very good:

```
DECLARE
tmp NUMBER;
tmp2 NUMBER;
o_id NUMBER := 999;

BEGIN

/*Checking if order exists */
  SELECT COUNT (*)
    INTO tmp
      FROM ORDERS
  WHERE ORDERID = o_id;               

  IF ( tmp = 0 ) THEN
 /* INSERT HERE */
  END IF;

  SELECT FULLFILLED INTO tmp2
  FROM ORDERS
  WHERE ORDERID = o_id;


  IF (tmp2 = 0) THEN
 /* UPDATE... */

  END IF;

end;
```

I would appreciate any advice, what should I look into to make this script efficient? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MERGE` statement is what you need. It is based on `SELECT` statement and let's you `UPDATE` or `INSERT` data using it's `WHEN (NOT) MATCHED THEN` clauses. Here's a good explanation with some examples: [Oracle Base MERGE Statement](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement).

Here's also some code snippet you might find useful:

```
DECLARE
    o_id        NUMBER := 999;
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO ORDERS o
    USING 
        (SELECT o_id AS orderid FROM dual) o_id
    ON
        (o.orderid = o_id.orderid)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            o.fulfilled = CASE WHEN o.fulfilled = 0 THEN 1 ELSE o.fulfilled END
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (fulfilled, <some_other_columns>)
        VALUES (1, <values_for_other_columns>);


END;
/
```

Comment: do you mind explaining why you used "dual" in the select statement under "USING"?

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on the merge statement: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Also called an "upsert".  Basically if the row does not exist, insert.  If it does, update.

It does what you are trying to do in one statement.

Comment: Thank you, will do.